# How to grant permission for the camera?

Tags: android

I just need a way to get permission for using the camera of the smartphone.
I wrote this code, but the permission request dialog doesn't appear.

in the onCreate:

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)) {
        } else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.CAMERA}, 1);
        }
    }

}



@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {
            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                // my code after granted permission

            } else {


            }
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When you stepped through your code in a debugger, what did you learn? Are you actually calling `requestPermissions()`?

Comment: @CommonsWare no, requestPermissions() is not called because "ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)" is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> requestPermissions() is not called because "ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this, Manifest.permission.CAMERA)" is true

Step #1: Show some rationale (dialog, snackbar, something inline in your UI, whatever)

Step #2: When the user taps on something specific in that rationale UI (e.g., OK button), call `requestPermissions()`

Or, if you do not want to show rationale for why you are requesting the permission, do not call `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`.

Comment: and how should I do if I want to show the permission request when users open the app ?

Comment: @xRobot: Um, execute the code in your question, with the modifications shown in my answer. Note that since you are using `ContextCompat` and `ActvityCompat`, you do not need the version check.